# Correct external HDD permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, external-hard-drive

I have just reformatted a 2T external to use the `EXT4` file-system with `GPT` partitioning from `NTFS` using `ms-dos`.

Currently the permissions for this device are 755.

I think this is correct, but I am curious about the safety / optimal set-up of permissions of an external after reading into the dangers of 777'ing the `/var/www` folder (as an example).

Comment: Can you give us more details of the setup you're using? It's a bit too broad to answer as it stands.

Comment: Simply a personal external HDD to use with my laptop